# Finding all eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I want to find all eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of the following graph(Graph spectrum), where $G$ and $H$ are complete graphs with $n$ and $m$ vertices, respectively, for positive integers $n,m \ge 3$.

[image]

Using Interlacing Theorem and by deleting the vertices $x$ and $y$, I can find some eigenvalues that are equal to $-1$. Also by Schwenk Theorem, I can find the characteristic polynomial of this graph, but finding the roots of such polynomial is not simple. Furthermore, we can use $\Sigma_{i=1}^{m+n+2}{\lambda_i^{k}}$ that is equal to the number of closed walks of length $k$ in this graph, but I could not find all eigenvalues with this method because the resulted system of equations is too hard to solve without using some softwares.

I am looking for some simple methods for finding the spectrum of such graphs, but I don't know it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There will be a space of dimension $m+n-2$, spanned by eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ that take the value zero on $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$. This gives a factor of $(x+1)^{m+n-2}$ in the characteristic polynomial. The remaining six eigenvalues are zeros of a degree six polynomial with coefficients depending on $m$ and $n$. In general (if $m\ne n$) there will be no useful formula for the zeros. If $m=n$ this polynomial will factor into two cubics, and there will be very messy formulas.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: Thank you so much for your helpful comment. I have to mention that the vertex $w$ is belong to the graph $G=K_n$ and the vertex $z$ is belong to the graph $H=K_m$. So the number of vertices of this graph is equal to $m+n+2$. With this assumption, would you please explain what are the form of eigenvectors of the eigenvalue $-1$? Furthermore, is it possible to find all eigenvalues of the graph that is constructed from connecting a leaf to one vertex of a complete graph?

Comment: The eigenvectors that are zero on $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ form a subspace with dimension $m+n-2$ and all these vectors have eigenvalue $-1$. Any vector that is zero on the four middle vertices and sums to zero on vertices in $G\setminus w$ and $H\setminus z$ will be an eigenvector.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: Nice answer. Thank you so much. By considering $m+n−4$ eigenvalues equal to $−1$, six eigenvalues will be remain that are not $-1$ and cannot be evaluated easily. Am I right?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: With this technique or other methods, is it possible to find all eigenvalues of the graph that is constructed from adding a pendant to one vertex of a complete graph?

Comment: What I use is the theory of equitable partitions, but there isn't room to treat that here.